# setup.py specify a package dependency that can be fulfilled by different packages?

Tags: python

Is there a way to specify as part of your requirements in setup.py if more than one package can fulfill a dependency?

For Example, pandas requires either the `xwlt` or `XlsxWriter` package for writing out excel files but not both.